# How to concatenate a pair of coordinates within a sublist consecutively in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list of coordinates:

```
coords=[[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], [(7,8),(9,10)], [(11,12),(13,14),(15,16),(17,18)]]
```

I would like to convert it to a following list if possible using itertools python (not necessarily):

```
coords=[((1,2),(3,4)), ((3,4),(5,6)), ((7,8),(9,10)), ((11,12),(13,14)), ((13,14),(15,16)), ((15,16),(17,18))]
```

Thank you

I have tried the following for iterating over one list but not nested list:

```
zip(coords[:-1],coords[1:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension. Pair adjacent tuples in each sub-list by zipping the sub-list with itself but with an offset of 1:

```
[p for t in coords for p in zip(t, t[1:])]
```

This returns:

```
[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((3, 4), (5, 6)), ((7, 8), (9, 10)), ((11, 12), (13, 14)), ((13, 14), (15, 16)), ((15, 16), (17, 18))]
```